# How do I extend a nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependencies

I want to make an "extension" to a 2D Game Engine that allows displaying basic 3D. I've tried google but it only results in unrelated topics. My intuition tells me it's not even possible, because I want to depend on the game engine and then not include it.

I don't want my extension package to replace the base package. People should still have to download the original package for my extension to work. Otherwise I'd just be making my own version of the base package. I only want to add a single namespace with a few classes.

My extension depends on the engine itself, obviously. I assume it's impossible, knowing how dependencies work, but I could be wrong - that's why I'm asking.